# How to create 'KeyDown' event programmatically for multiple DataGridview in same windows form?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

When i tried to create `KeyDown` event for DataGridview in c# it shows error " `handler Control_KeyDown already exists in this class` ".

I have already created `KeyDown` event for DataGridview1 in `DataGridview1_EditingControlShowing` event.

```
e.Control.KeyDown +=new KeyEventHandler(Control_KeyDown);
```

I want to create same event for DataGridview2, so in DataGridview2_EditingControlShowing event

```
e.Control.KeyDown +=new KeyEventHandler(Control_KeyDown); // here the above error shown.So i tried

DataGridview2.KeyPress +=new KeyEventHandler(Control_KeyDown); // it compiles, but event not firing.
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to handle  `keypress` event your event handler might be `KeyPressEventArgs`
and for `keydown` your event handler should be  `PreviewKeyDownEventArgs`

E.g

```
dataGirdView1.KeyPress += OnDataGirdView1_KeyPress;

private void OnDataGirdView1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

for Key down event

```
 dataGirdView1.PreviewKeyDown  += dataGridView1_PreviewKeyDown;


private void dataGridView1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: the 'keydown' or 'keypress' is not firing in second gridview